# Site is down after stop/start of instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had to increase the capacity of an instance. So I first took a snapshot of the volume, then stopped the instance and changed the type from t1.micro to m1.medium and started the instance again.

But the site it down and I cannot access it, any help appreciated.

I have to increase the capacity on a number of other instances as well, so I want to get this one working before I attempt the rest.

Regards.

*EDIT*

After doing a bit of digging, I think the instance has been assigned a new internal & public IP address.

Comment: This is why Elastic IPs are *awesome*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provision an elastic IP and associate that with your instance. Then point your DNS name to that IP.

Since you are not running in a VPC, you will need to re-associate this EIP with your instance any time you stop/start it.

If you want to automate EIP association, you can deploy the EC2 command line tools to your instance along with proper credentials, and then have it run this on boot:

```
$ ec2-associate-address <IP Address> -i <Instance ID>
```